# How to change the item's width and height when we use StaggeredGridLayoutManager

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I know how to use StaggeredGridLayoutManager and RecyclerView to draw a staggered grid, like this.[pic For staggered grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G0rKD.png) . But in this case all the item has the same width. I want change the width and height at the same time to do a layout like this:
[expected image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmxdt.png)
How to do that? Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: You are able to make ANY layout just with the RelativeLayout.

Answer (score 0):

You can only change one field using `StaggeredGridLayoutManager`:height for vertical layout and width for horizontal layout.

Comment: Thank you, If I want to a layout like the [expected image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/zmxdt.png), could you give me any suggestion?

Comment: @Fred Well, it depends on whether you want to add/delete/update items dynamically or not. If your items are determined from the beginning and will not be changed, just use subclass of `ViewGroup` to acheive that. Otherwise, it is going to be complicated. I'm not irritating you, but considering that you asked this question, you don't know the difficulty of realizing your thoughts. So it's very hard for you to do that. Just learn more and do simpler at first. That's my suggestion. Sorry for that if I've still annoyed you.